# How to do version control for SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, svn, version-control

I want to get my databases under version control.

I'll always want to have at least *some* data in there (as [alumb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80/alumb) mentions: user types and administrators). I'll also often want a large collection of generated test data for performance measurements.

How would I apply version control to my database?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Martin Fowler wrote my favorite article on the subject, http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html.  I choose not to put schema dumps in under version control as *alumb* and others suggest because I want an easy way to upgrade my production database.

For a web application where I'll have a single production database instance, I use two techniques:

## Database Upgrade Scripts

A sequence database upgrade scripts that contain the DDL necessary to move the schema from version N to N+1.  (These go in your version control system.)  A _version_history_ table, something like

```
create table VersionHistory (
    Version int primary key,
    UpgradeStart datetime not null,
    UpgradeEnd datetime
    );
```

gets a new entry every time an upgrade script runs which corresponds to the new version.

This ensures that it's easy to see what version of the database schema exists and that database upgrade scripts are run only once.  Again, these are **not** database dumps.  Rather, each script represents the **changes** necessary to move from one version to the next.  They're the script that you apply to your production database to "upgrade" it.

## Developer Sandbox Synchronization

1. A script to backup, sanitize, and shrink a production database.  Run this after each upgrade to the production DB.
2. A script to restore (and tweak, if necessary) the backup on a developer's workstation.  Each developer runs this script after each upgrade to the production DB.

*A caveat: My automated tests run against a schema-correct but empty database, so this advice will not perfectly suit your needs.*

Comment: Version controlling full schema scripts is very useful for reference purposes. For instance, it is impossible to see what exactly was changed in a stored procedure by looking at ALTER PROCEDURE statement.

Comment: Dumping (and versioning) the full DB schema after running new upgrade scripts is a good way to make information available to other tools in your build/deploy process as well. Also, having the full schema in a script means being able to "spin up" a fresh database without going through all the migration steps. It also makes it possible to diff the current version against accumulated previous versions.

Comment: Are saying that you put upgrade scripts in source control, nut do not put rollback ones there?

Comment: I have a habit of maintaining a full create and drop script, as well as delta scripts for updating existing db instances up to date. Both go into version control. The delta scripts are named according to revision numbers. That way it's easy to automate db patching with an update script.

Comment: @nikc.org's answer, plus post-commit hooks for automation.

Comment: What's really frustrating is that a VS database project can generate the scripts needed for these schema updates, but it will directly apply them.  It won't handle the version history stuff.  You have to manually do that, and if you even once forget to manually add the update script you're screwed because your DB will already be updated and the DB project won't generate that same update script again.  I wish there were a project type that handled *versioned* database management.

Comment: I do this too, but I keep an ordinary backup file in source control in place of a full-generation script.  Faster and less problem-prone, in my experience.  It does make it slightly harder to diff between arbitrary versions, but then again doing this doesn't come up that often, and the update scripts are perfectly searchable anyway, which should suffice, since all changes go through them.  Also, for version numbers inside the DB itself, I put an Extended Property on the database object.  This way it's part of the schema instead of part of the data.

Comment: What if I want to roll back the database to an earlier version?

Answer (score 47):

There are several commercial products that provide this functionality:

- [RedGate SQL Source Control](https://red-gate.com)
- [VersionSQL](https://www.versionsql.com)
- [ApexSQL](https://www.apexsql.com/)

### For RedGate Users

If you are using Red Gate's SQL Compare product - you can do object-level comparisons, and generate change scripts. It also allows you to export your database objects into a folder hierarchy organized by object type, with one [objectname].sql creation script per object in these directories.  The object-type hierarchy is like this:

\Functions
\Security
\Security\Roles
\Security\Schemas
\Security\Users
\Stored Procedures
\Tables

If you dump your scripts to the same root directory after you make changes, you can use this to update your SVN repo, and keep a running history of each object individually.

Comment: We've just released SQL Source Control, which integrates the SQL Compare behavior you describe into SSMS, and links to SVN and TFS. I've added a separate answer to this question that describes in more detail what it does. http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

Answer (score 41):

This is one of the "hard problems" surrounding development. As far as I know there are no perfect solutions.

If you only need to store the database structure and not the data you can export the database as SQL queries. (in Enterprise Manager: Right click on database -> Generate SQL script. I recommend setting the "create one file per object" on the options tab) You can then commit these text files to svn and make use of svn's diff and logging functions.

I have this tied together with a Batch script that takes a couple parameters and sets up the database. I also added some additional queries that enter default data like user types and the admin user. (If you want more info on this, post something and I can put the script somewhere accessible)

If you need to keep all of the data as well, I recommend keeping a back up of the database and using Redgate (http://www.red-gate.com/) products to do the comparisons. They don't come cheap, but they are worth every penny.

Comment: regarding the data - you can use [OffScale DataGrove](http://off-scale.com) to save versions of your entire DB (data included). You can later use it to spawn up two virtual copies of your DB which can be compared with red-gate's product.
It also saves you the need to generate test data - you can just save versions of the DB to match the different test-cases (again, full, virtual copies of the entire DB)

Comment: How do you work out which order to run the database scripts if you use the "one file per object" option?

Comment: @Taichman: DataGrove does not seem to support SQL server, and as such has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 41):

First, you must choose the version control system that is right for you:

- Centralized Version Control system - a standard system where users check out/check in before/after they work on files, and the files are being kept in a single central server
- Distributed Version Control system - a system where the repository is being cloned, and each clone is actually the full backup of the repository, so if any server crashes, then any cloned repository can be used to restore it
  After choosing the right system for your needs, you'll need to setup the repository which is the core of every version control system
  All this is explained in the following article: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-source-control-part-i-understanding-source-control-basics/

After setting up a repository, and in case of a central version control system a working folder, you can read [this article](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-source-control-part-ii-integration/). It shows how to setup source control in a development environment using:

- SQL Server Management Studio via the MSSCCI provider,
- Visual Studio and SQL Server Data Tools
- A 3rd party tool ApexSQL Source Control

Answer (score 21):

+1 for everyone who's recommended the RedGate tools, with an additional recommendation and a caveat.

SqlCompare also has a decently documented API: so you can, for instance, write a console app which syncs your source controlled scripts folder with a CI integration testing database on checkin, so that when someone checks in a change to the schema from their scripts folder it's automatically deployed along with the matching application code change. This helps close the gap with developers who are forgetful about propagating changes in their local db up to a shared development DB (about half of us, I think :) ).

A caveat is that with a scripted solution or otherwise, the RedGate tools are sufficiently smooth that it's easy to forget about SQL realities underlying the abstraction. If you rename all the columns in a table, SqlCompare has no way to map the old columns to the new columns and will drop all the data in the table. It will generate warnings but I've seen people click past that. There's a general point here worth making, I think, that you can only automate DB versioning and upgrade so far - the abstractions are very leaky.

Comment: So there should be a system that tracks what columns you are changing and remember the mappings from old column names to the new column names.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that for database changes that have ambiguity (and therefore need an element of "developer intent"), a migrations-based solution is the appropriate solution. Redgate now has ReadyRoll that satisfies this versioning approach.

Answer (score 18):

With VS 2010, use the Database project.

1. Script out your database
2. Make changes to scripts or directly on
   your db server
3. Sync up using Data >
       Schema Compare

Makes a perfect DB versioning solution, and makes syncing DB's a breeze.

Comment: Yeah but unfortunately you have to remember to "generate script" every single time.  If you directly update the database, you lose the ability to generate the update script for that delta.  If only database projects would have some built-in functionality for versioning.

Answer (score 13):

It is a good approach to save database scripts into version control with change scripts so that you can upgrade any one database you have. Also you might want to save schemas for different versions so that you can create a full database without having to apply all the change scripts. Handling the scripts should be automated so that you don't have to do manual work.

I think its important to have a separate database for every developer and not use a shared database. That way the developers can create test cases and development phases independently from other developers.

The automating tool should have means for handling database metadata, which tells what databases are in what state of development and which tables contain version controllable data and so on.

Answer (score 12):

You could also look at a migrations solution.  These allow you to specify your database schema in C# code, and roll your database version up and down using MSBuild.

I'm currently using [DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/), and it's been working well.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't mention any specifics about your target environment or constraints, so this may not be entirely applicable... but if you're looking for a way to effectively track an evolving DB schema and aren't adverse to the idea of using Ruby, ActiveRecord's migrations are right up your alley.

Migrations programatically define database transformations using a Ruby DSL; each transformation can be applied or (usually) rolled back, allowing you to jump to a different version of your DB schema at any given point in time. The file defining these transformations can be checked into version control like any other piece of source code.

Because migrations are a part of [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.com/), they typically find use in full-stack Rails apps; however, you can use ActiveRecord independent of Rails with minimal effort. See [here](http://rails.aizatto.com/2007/05/27/activerecord-migrations-without-rails/) for a more detailed treatment of using AR's migrations outside of Rails.

Answer (score 9):

It's simple.

1. When the base project is ready then you must create full database script. This script is commited to SVN. It is first version.
2. After that all developers creates change scripts (ALTER..., new tables, sprocs, etc).
3. When you need current version then you should execute all new change scripts.
4. When app is released to production then you go back to 1 (but then it will be successive version of course).

Nant will help you to execute those change scripts. :)

And remember. Everything works fine when there is discipline. Every time when database change is commited then corresponding functions in code are commited too.

Comment: After some years I say: Use FluentMigrator (or similar tool for your platform).

Answer (score 8):

If you have a small database and you want to version the entire thing, [this batch script](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/10/28/Batch-files-to-check-SQL-2005-_2800_MDF_2900_-files-in-and-out-of-Subversion-source-control.aspx) might help. It detaches, compresses, and checks a MSSQL database MDF file in to Subversion.

If you mostly want to version your schema and just have a small amount of reference data, you can possibly use [SubSonic Migrations](http://web.archive.org/web/20120419154556/http://blog.wekeroad.com:80/blog/subsonic-using-migrations) to handle that. The benefit there is that you can easily migrate up or down to any specific version.

Answer (score 8):

Because our app has to work across multiple RDBMSs, we store our schema definition in version control using the database-neutral [Torque](http://db.apache.org/torque/) format (XML). We also version-control the reference data for our database in XML format as follows (where "Relationship" is one of the reference tables):

```
  <Relationship RelationshipID="1" InternalName="Manager"/>
  <Relationship RelationshipID="2" InternalName="Delegate"/>
  etc.
```

We then use home-grown tools to generate the schema upgrade and reference data upgrade scripts that are required to go from version X of the database to version X + 1.

Answer (score 7):

We don't store the database schema, we store the changes to the database.  What we do is store the schema changes so that we build a change script for any version of the database and apply it to our customer's databases.  I wrote an database utility app that gets distributed with our main application that can read that script and know which updates need to be applied.  It also has enough smarts to refresh views and stored procedures as needed.

Answer (score 7):

To make the dump to a source code control system that little bit faster, you can see which objects have changed since last time by using the version information in sysobjects.

**Setup:** Create a table in each database you want to check incrementally to hold the version information from the last time you checked it (empty on the first run). Clear this table if you want to re-scan your whole data structure.

```
IF ISNULL(OBJECT_ID('last_run_sysversions'), 0) <> 0 DROP TABLE last_run_sysversions
CREATE TABLE last_run_sysversions (
    name varchar(128), 
    id int, base_schema_ver int,
    schema_ver int,
    type char(2)
)
```

**Normal running mode:** You can take the results from this sql, and generate sql scripts for just the ones you're interested in, and put them into a source control of your choice.

```
IF ISNULL(OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp'), 0) <> 0 DROP TABLE #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    name varchar(128), 
    id int, base_schema_ver int,
    schema_ver int,
    type char(2)
)

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Insert the values from the end of the last run into #tmp
INSERT #tmp (name, id, base_schema_ver, schema_ver, type) 
SELECT name, id, base_schema_ver, schema_ver, type FROM last_run_sysversions

DELETE last_run_sysversions
INSERT last_run_sysversions (name, id, base_schema_ver, schema_ver, type)
SELECT name, id, base_schema_ver, schema_ver, type FROM sysobjects

-- This next bit lists all differences to scripts.
SET NOCOUNT OFF

--Renamed.
SELECT 'renamed' AS ChangeType, t.name, o.name AS extra_info, 1 AS Priority
FROM sysobjects o INNER JOIN #tmp t ON o.id = t.id
WHERE o.name <> t.name /*COLLATE*/
AND o.type IN ('TR', 'P' ,'U' ,'V')
UNION 

--Changed (using alter)
SELECT 'changed' AS ChangeType, o.name /*COLLATE*/, 
       'altered' AS extra_info, 2 AS Priority
FROM sysobjects o INNER JOIN #tmp t ON o.id = t.id 
WHERE (
   o.base_schema_ver <> t.base_schema_ver
OR o.schema_ver      <> t.schema_ver
)
AND  o.type IN ('TR', 'P' ,'U' ,'V')
AND  o.name NOT IN ( SELECT oi.name 
         FROM sysobjects oi INNER JOIN #tmp ti ON oi.id = ti.id
         WHERE oi.name <> ti.name /*COLLATE*/
         AND oi.type IN ('TR', 'P' ,'U' ,'V')) 
UNION

--Changed (actually dropped and recreated [but not renamed])
SELECT 'changed' AS ChangeType, t.name, 'dropped' AS extra_info, 2 AS Priority
FROM #tmp t
WHERE    t.name IN ( SELECT ti.name /*COLLATE*/ FROM #tmp ti
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects oi
                           WHERE oi.id = ti.id))
AND  t.name IN ( SELECT oi.name /*COLLATE*/ FROM sysobjects oi
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmp ti
                           WHERE oi.id = ti.id)
         AND   oi.type  IN ('TR', 'P' ,'U' ,'V'))
UNION

--Deleted
SELECT 'deleted' AS ChangeType, t.name, '' AS extra_info, 0 AS Priority
FROM #tmp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects o
                  WHERE o.id = t.id)
AND t.name NOT IN (  SELECT oi.name /*COLLATE*/ FROM sysobjects oi
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmp ti
                           WHERE oi.id = ti.id)
         AND   oi.type  IN ('TR', 'P' ,'U' ,'V'))
UNION

--Added
SELECT 'added' AS ChangeType, o.name /*COLLATE*/, '' AS extra_info, 4 AS Priority
FROM sysobjects o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmp t
                  WHERE o.id = t.id)
AND      o.type  IN ('TR', 'P' ,'U' ,'V')
AND  o.name NOT IN ( SELECT ti.name /*COLLATE*/ FROM #tmp ti
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects oi
                           WHERE oi.id = ti.id))
ORDER BY Priority ASC
```

**Note:** If you use a non-standard collation in any of your databases, you will need to replace `/* COLLATE */` with your database collation. i.e. `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`

Answer (score 6):

The typical solution is to dump the database as necessary and backup those files.

Depending on your development platform, there may be opensource plugins available. Rolling your own code to do it is usually fairly trivial.

Note: You may want to backup the database dump instead of putting it into version control.  The files can get huge fast in version control, and cause your entire source control system to become slow (I'm recalling a CVS horror story at the moment).

Answer (score 6):

We needed to version our SQL database after we migrated to an x64 platform and our old version broke with the migration.  We wrote a C# application which used SQLDMO to map out all of the SQL objects to a folder:

```
                Root
                    ServerName
                       DatabaseName
                          Schema Objects
                             Database Triggers*
                                .ddltrigger.sql
                             Functions
                                ..function.sql
                             Security
                                Roles
                                   Application Roles
                                      .approle.sql
                                   Database Roles
                                      .role.sql
                                Schemas*
                                   .schema.sql
                                Users
                                   .user.sql
                             Storage
                                Full Text Catalogs*
                                   .fulltext.sql
                             Stored Procedures
                                ..proc.sql
                             Synonyms*
                                .synonym.sql
                             Tables
                                ..table.sql
                                Constraints
                                   ...chkconst.sql
                                   ...defconst.sql
                                Indexes
                                   ...index.sql
                                Keys
                                   ...fkey.sql
                                   ...pkey.sql
                                   ...ukey.sql
                                Triggers
                                   ...trigger.sql
                             Types
                                User-defined Data Types
                                   ..uddt.sql
                                XML Schema Collections*
                                   ..xmlschema.sql
                             Views
                                ..view.sql
                                Indexes
                                   ...index.sql
                                Triggers
                                   ...trigger.sql
```

The application would then compare the newly written version with the version stored in SVN, and if there were differences it would update SVN.
We determined that running the process once a night was sufficient since we did not make that many changes to SQL. It allows us to track changes to all the objects we care about plus it allows us to rebuild our full schema in the event of a serious problem.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with ESV answer and for that exact reason I started a little project a while back to help maintain database updates in a very simple file which could then be maintained a long side out source code. It allows easy updates to developers as well as UAT and Production. The tool works on SQL Server and MySQL.

Some project features:

- Allows schema changes
- Allows value tree population
- Allows separate test data inserts for eg. UAT
- Allows option for rollback (not automated)
- Maintains support for SQL server and MySQL
- Has the ability to import your existing database into version control with one simple command (SQL server only ... still working on MySQL)

Please check out the [code](http://code.google.com/p/databaseversioncontrol/) for some more information.

Answer (score 6):

It's a very old question, however, many people are trying to solve this even now. All they have to do is to research about Visual Studio Database Projects. Without this, any database development looks very feeble. From code organization to deployment to versioning, it simplifies everything.

Comment: Azure Data Studio has database projects, too.

Answer (score 5):

A while ago I found a VB bas module that used DMO and VSS objects to get an entire db scripted off and into VSS. I turned it into a VB Script and posted it [here](http://glossopian.co.uk/pmwiki.php?n=Main.DBtoVSS). You can easily take out the VSS calls and use the DMO stuff to generate all the scripts, and then call SVN from the same batch file that calls the VBScript to check them in.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also using a version in the database stored via the database extended properties family of procedures. My application has scripts for each version step (ie. move from 1.1 to 1.2). When deployed, it looks at the current version and then runs the scripts one by one until it reaches the last app version. There is no script that has the straight 'final' version, even deploy on a clean DB does the deploy via a series of upgrade steps.

Now what I like to add is that I've seen two days ago a presentation on the MS campus about the new and upcoming VS DB edition. The presentation was focused specifically on this topic and I was blown out of the water. You should definitely check it out, the new facilities are focused on keeping schema definition in T-SQL scripts (CREATEs), a runtime delta engine to compare deployment schema with defined schema and doing the delta ALTERs and integration with source code integration, up to and including MSBUILD continuous integration for automated build drops. The drop will contain a new file type, the .dbschema files, that can be taken to the deployment site and a command line tool can do the actual 'deltas' and run the deployment.
I have a blog entry on this topic with links to the VSDE downloads, you should check them out: http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the solution is twofold:

1. You need to handle changes to the development database that are done by multiple developers during development.
2. You need to handle database upgrades in customers sites.

In order to handle #1 you'll need a strong database diff/merge tool. The best tool should be able to perform automatic merge as much as possible while allowing you to resolve unhandled conflicts manually.

The perfect tool should handle merge operations by using a 3-way merge algorithm that brings into account the changes that were made in the THEIRS database and the MINE database, relative to the BASE database.

I wrote a commercial tool that provides manual merge support for SQLite databases and I'm currently adding support for 3-way merge algorithm for SQLite. Check it out at http://www.sqlitecompare.com

In order to handle #2 you will need an upgrade framework in place.

The basic idea is to develop an automatic upgrade framework that knows how to upgrade from an existing SQL schema to the newer SQL schema and can build an upgrade path for every existing DB installation.

Check out my article on the subject in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlite_upgrade.aspx to get a general idea of what I'm talking about.

Good Luck

Liron Levi