# How do you version your database schema?

Tags: sql, mysql, schema, versioning

How do you prepare your SQL deltas? do you manually save each schema-changing SQL to a delta folder, or do you have some kind of an automated diffing process?

I am interested in conventions for versioning database schema along with the source code. Perhaps a pre-commit hook that diffs the schema?

Also, what options for diffing deltas exist aside from [DbDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/)?

**EDIT:** seeing the answers I would like to clarify that I am familiar with the standard scheme for running a database migration using deltas. My question is about creating the deltas themselves, preferably automatically.

Also, the versioning is for PHP and MySQL if it makes a difference. (No Ruby solutions please).

Comment: I use [schemasync](https://github.com/mmatuson/SchemaSync) to generate a patch (and a rollback script). These are added to the SVN repo. It's not perfect but it works well for me. Plus, deploying schema changes is quite easy with schemasync

Comment: This link appears empty -- does this still exist?

Comment: Looks like it's moved: https://github.com/mmatuson/SchemaSync

Answer (score 67, accepted):

See

[Is there a version control system for database structure changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308/is-there-a-version-control-system-for-database-structure-changes)

[How do I version my MS SQL database in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173/how-do-i-version-my-ms-sql-database-in-svn)

and Jeff's article

[Get Your Database Under Version Control](http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/)

I feel your pain, and I wish there were a better answer.  This might be closer to what you were looking for.

[Mechanisms for tracking DB schema changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607/mechanisms-for-tracking-db-schema-changes#22535)

Generally, I feel there is no adequate, accepted solution to this, and I roll my own in this area.

Comment: As you can tell from my question, I am aware of the concept of deltas. My question is about conventions for creating those, preferably automatically.

Comment: I guess I'll be rolling my own then... ;)

Comment: Have you tried out DBDiff: https://github.com/DBDiff/DBDiff ? It's a good fit for what you're looking for @EranGalperin as it does automated migrations for both schema and data in SQL. _Disclosure_ I'm the developer behind it!

Answer (score 4):

You might take a look at another, similar thread: [How do I version my MS SQL database in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173/how-do-i-version-my-ms-sql-database-in-svn).

Answer (score 4):

If you are still looking for options : have a look at neXtep designer. It is a free GPL database development environment based on the concepts of version control. In the environment you always work with versioned entities and can focus on the data model development. Once a release is done, the SQL generation engine plugged on the version control system can generate any delta you need between 2 versions, and will offer you some delivery mechanism if you need.

Among other things, you can synchronize and reverse synchronize your database during developments, create data model diagrams, query your database using integrated SQL clients, etc.

Have a look at the wiki for more information : 
http://www.nextep-softwares.com/wiki

It currently supports Oracle, MySql and PostgreSql and is in java so the product runs on windows, linux and mac.

Answer (score 3):

I don't manage deltas.  I make changes to a master database and have a tool that creates an XML based build script based on the master database.

When it comes time to upgrade an existing database I have a program that uses the XML based build script to create a new database and the bare tables.  I then copy the data over from the old database using INSERT INTO x SELECT FROM y and then apply all indexes, constraints and triggers.

New tables, new columns, deleted columns all get handled automatically and with a few little tricks to adjust the copy routine I can handle column renames, column type changes and other basic refactorings.

I wouldn't recommend this solution on a database with a huge amount of data but I regularly update a database that is over 1GB with 400 tables.

Comment: This sounds somewhat cumbersome, especially when dealing with multiple developers. Also the build process sounds demanding, and I would like to be as simple as possible.

Comment: I admit it took a while to get right but now it requires almost no effort to prep an upgrade and even less to perform one.  Also, one thing I like is that I can do interim hotfix changes and it has no impact on the upgrade procedure.  Each upgrade is a fresh new DB.

Answer (score 3):

I make sure that schema changes are always additive. So I don't drop columns and tables, because that would zap the data and cannot be rolled back later. This way the code that uses the database can be rolled back without losing data or functionality.

I have a migration script that contains statements that creates tables and columns if they don't exist yet and fills them with data.

The migration script runs whenever the production code is updated and after new installs.

When I would like to drop something, I do it by removing them from the database install script and the migration script so these obsolete schema elements will be gradually phased out in new installs. With the disadvantage that new installs cannot downgrade to an older version before the install.

And of course I execute DDLs via these scripts and never directly on the database to keep things in sync.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which RDBMS you're using, but if it's MS SQL Server, Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) has been indispensable to us in creating deltas between object creation scripts.

Comment: It's for Mysql, I've updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I'm not one to toot my own horn, but I've developed an internal web app to track changes to database schemas and create versioned update scripts.

This tool is called [Brazil](http://github.com/jbripley/brazil/tree/master) and is now open source under a MIT license. Brazil is ruby / ruby on rails based and supports change deployment to any database that [Ruby DBI](http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/) supports (MySQL, ODBC, Oracle, Postgres, SQLite).

Support for putting the update scripts in version control is planned.

Comment: Brazil looks pretty good, too bad I'm using mainly PHP. Ever considered porting the system?

Answer (score 2):

http://bitbucket.org/idler/mmp - schema versioning tool for mysql, writed in PHP

Answer (score 1):

We're exporting the data to a portable format (using our toolchain), then importing it to a new schema. no need for delta SQL. Highly recommended.

Comment: What is this portable format? and how do you import it into the new schema applying only the differences from the previous version?

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in this topic too.

There are [some discussions on this topic in the Django wiki](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SchemaEvolution).

Interestingly, it looks like [CakePHP has schema versioning built-in](http://book.cakephp.org/view/735/Generating-and-using-Schema-files) using just `cake schema generate` command.

Comment: From what I read about cake's solution - it is versioning in a very basic sense, however it has no diffing capabilities so it is of no use to me.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org) database for most development and I use [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org) administration tool for it. It has a nice option to log all changes. It can log everything to a one big file, or one file per database change. I use this second option, and then I store each script in version control software - earlier I used Subversion, now I use Git.

I assume you can find some MySQL tool that has the same logging feature like FlameRobin does for Firebird.

In one of database tables, I store the *version number* of the database structure, so I can upgrade any database easily. I also wrote a simple PHP script that executes those SQL scripts one by one on any target database (database path and username/password are supplied on the command line).

There's also an option to log all DML (insert, update delete) statements, and I activate this while modifying some 'default' data that each database contains.

I wrote a nice white paper on how I do all this in detail. You can download the paper in .pdf format along with demo PHP scripts from [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=58913&package_id=212064).

Answer (score 1):

I also developed a set of PHP scripts where developers can submit their deltasql scripts to a central repository.

In one of the database tables (called TBSYNCHRONIZE), I store the version number of the latest executed script, so I can upgrade any database easily by using the web interface or a client developed on purpose for Eclipse.

The web interface allows to manage several projects. It supports also database "branches".

You can test the application at http://www.gpu-grid.net/deltasql (if you login as admin with password testdbsync).
The application is open source and can be downloaded here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/deltasql

deltasql is used productively in Switzerland and India, and is popular in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

Some months ago I searched tool for versioning MySQL schema. I found many useful tools, like Doctrine migration, RoR migration, some tools writen in Java and Python.

But no one of them was satisfied my requirements.

My requirements:

1. No requirements , exclude PHP and MySQL
2. No schema configuration files, like schema.yml in Doctrine
3. Able to read current schema from connection and create new migration script, than represent identical schema in other installations of application.

I started to write my migration tool, and today I have beta version.

Please, try it, if you have an interest in this topic.
Please send me future requests and bugreports.

Source code: bitbucket.org/idler/mmp/src
Overview in English: bitbucket.org/idler/mmp/wiki/Home
Overview in Russian: antonoff.info/development/mysql-migration-with-php-project

Comment: You also have a new tool: DBV: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13837473/6309

Answer (score 1):

I use http://code.google.com/p/oracle-ddl2svn/

Answer (score 1):

I am using strict versioning of the database schema (tracked in a separate table). Scripts are stored in version control, but they all verify current schema version before making any change.

Here is the full implementation for SQL Server (the same solution could be developed for MySQL if needed): [How to Maintain SQL Server Database Schema Version](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/sql-schema-versioning)

Comment: I've just read your article. Do you still use this or have you since adopted an off-the-shelf solution such as DBUp or ReadyRoll?

Comment: Currently, all my projects rely on Entity Framework Code-First and I use its migrations to version the database. I have the solution from the article in a couple of legacy projects and I never replaced it. In other projects I used Redgate tools to manage schema and migrations.

Comment: Great that you're a Redgate user! If you want to use Redgate tools in conjunction with EF, it's possible: https://www.red-gate.com/blog/database-lifecycle-management/deploying-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-with-t-sql

Comment: I'll make sure to try it on next opportunity. It served us well, but I've changed the team in the meanwhile and now I'm experimenting with native EF support before pushing it forward.

Answer (score 1):

### For MySQL

When I land on a new DB:

Firstly, I check structure:

> ```
> mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -h __DB_HOSTNAME__ -u __DB_USERNAME__ -p __DB1_NAME__ | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g' > FILENAME_1.sql
> mysqldump --no-data --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -h __DB_HOSTNAME__ -u __DB_USERNAME__ -p __DB2_NAME__ | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g' > FILENAME_2.sql
> diff FILENAME_1.sql FILENAME_2.sql > DIFF_FILENAME.txt
> cat DIFF_FILENAME.txt | less
> ```
>
> Thanks to stackoverflow users I could write this quick script to find structure differences.
>
> *src : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718572/4457531 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328331/4457531*

In a second step, I check datas, table by table with `mysqldiff`. It's a bit archaic but a php loop based on `information_schema` datas make job surely

For versioning, I use the same way but I format a SQL update script (to upgrade or rollback) with diff results and I use version number convention *(with several modifications the version number look like an ip address)*.

```
initial version : 1.0.0
                  ^ ^ ^
                  | | |
structure change: - | |
datas added: -------- |
datas updated: --------
```