# how to compare two mysql databases on a mac?

Tags: mysql, database

hi i am using snow leopard and was wondering how i can compare two mysql databases? 
one of the dbs is located on a remote server while the other is local

thanks

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases

Comment: Haim's answer does provide a clue but no real solution, i am still interested in a way to compare two databases on a mac

Comment: Check this toolkit https://launchpad.net/percona-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

If you're well budgeted, or if that's a one time need, [RazorSQ](http://www.razorsql.com/)L can do it. There
are several competitors as well.

Comment: How exactly can you do that in RazorSQL? Unfortunately I am unable to install mysqldiff on my Mac, so I am looking for an alternative, found this post, but am not sure how to get my alter table statements from RazorSQL. Thanks.