# Comparing two databases with mysqldump?

Tags: diff, mysql

I have two mysql databases which should be identical to each-other.  One was made by an old version of a script and another was made a new refactored version.

I need to show that these databases are identical.

I had the idea of getting a `mysqldump` for each one and comparing them with `diff`... but apparently it's not so simple.

It seems the order of the inserts in each `mysqldump` differs such that both files come out completely different from each-other (which they are not and it is easily discernable that the data is just showing up on different lines).

I am looking for a way to either order the output of `mysqldump` or use another method to show that these two databases are exactly the same (or if not point out the differences).

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: I have tried following this: http://2skies.com/docs/Comparing_mysql_tables_with_mysqldump_and_diff

but the results are ordered differently.

Comment: try http://www.mysqldiff.org/ its free

Comment: Have you checked this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases

Comment: mysqldiff appears to only compare structure (not content), but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `--compatible` flag that could help you [doc here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible).

You will assign it the `mysql` lowest version, for example:

```
mysqldump --compatible=mysql40
```

so your output should be the same for both version (assuming they are greater than 4.0, otherwise use `mysql323`).

Comment: Tried this and it does not make a difference.  I am not trying with one table which appears to be identical when I view the sorted data, however 29709 lines are found in the diff output...  Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @jeffp identical "sorted data" doesn't mean that data are phisically stored in the same way. You could try adding the `--order-by-primary` option flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Meld to compare dumps. Works well.