# Differences in magento1.4v and 1.5v databases

Tags: mysql, magento, schema, sql-update

I want to know is there any difference in catalog and eav tables of magento 1.4.1.1v and magento 1.5v. Difference in the sense, are there any fields are added or removed in catalog, eav tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would install fresh copies of both 1.4 and 1.5, then do a [structure-only dump](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mysql/dump-just-the-table-structure-to-a-file-in-mysql/) (phpmyadmin can do this too) of the databases, then Diff the resulting SQL files. This will show you the differences.

Here are a ton of other options to compare two MySQl DBs:
[Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases)

Cheers

Comment: This is probably the quickest and easiest. There is a tremendous lag on official documentation if you ever get it. There's always a difference on major .V changes. 1.3.1.1 220 tables to 1.4.1.1 310 tables. And column renames tend to be one of the bugbears of template updating.

Answer (score 0):

See this Magento Wiki: [Magento Database Diagram](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram)

Also see http://www.magereverse.com/

MAGEREVERSE is an online Database Diagram Tool dedicated to Magento eCommerce.

Hope this helps.