# Drupal: Merge databases

Tags: database, drupal

I am working with a dev database for add a new section in a web site.

I finish all changes, and now, i have to send some people all these changes (contents, content types, blocks, views, templates, files, images etc).

I kwnow i can export blocks, views and content types, but how can i send these contents?

Which is the best way to merge/send the changes made in development to the final database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features module is your best bet: http://drupal.org/project/features

I have been using it for this purpose with great results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which database you're using, but most likely MySQL. In that case, have a look at this post: [Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases)
You can use any of these tools to compare two databases and create and update-script.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I used the [Node Export Module](http://drupal.org/project/node_export)  to move content between two Drupal installations. You export from one and import on the other. It can export in a variety of editable formats, which is useful if you need to do some data massaging between the export and the import.