# Best practice to version a database

Tags: mysql, database, version

I am doing an ongoing MySQL database development. I have a create database script and a set of scripts to patch it along the time. In those patch I need to check if the target database is the correct version. I am thinking to add a table to my schema for this purpose but it might overkill this problem.

I am wondering what is the best practice to do it.

THanks,

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases

Comment: @Feng, was that answer helpful? If so, please accept it; or, let me know your additional concern.

Comment: Check https://github.com/m-szalik/dbpatch-maven-plugin it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I do for a number of databases - a table called schema_history, that my scripts which update the schema always add a row to: with date, version ID, purpose, etc. I can see what version any database is by looking at the last record in schema_history -- very handy.

I recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am using maven plugin for that. It can track your database changes as well as apply missing SQL scripts.

https://github.com/m-szalik/dbpatch-maven-plugin