# How to Schema Diff two databases using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, schema, mysql-workbench

Does anyone know how to pull a database Scheme Diff for two databases using MySQL Workbench.  v5.2 states it has this feature, but I can't seem to find it. I must use MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases

Comment: How about with MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The database diff tool is part of the MySQL Utilities that you can access through MySQL Workbench in `Plugins -> Start Shell for MySQL Utilities`. You can find the [relevant documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-utilities-1.6-en/mysqldiff.html).

Comment: The [`mysqldbcompare`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-utilities-1.6-en/mysqldbcompare.html) tool, which uses mysqldiff I think, may be a better option for a whole database. I'm using `--run-all-tests --skip-row-count --skip-data-check` options to get only schema differences. Only downside I see so far is it just notifies of any objects missing in one of the databases rather than providing `CREATE` statements when using `--difftype=sql`.

Answer (score 40):

If you don't see this option directly you have to:

1. Click `File` and `New model`
2. On the new model window which has been opened, click `Database` and `Compare schemas`.

Comment: this gives a report only about the differences is there any way to generate a script on apply these to the DB directly

Answer (score 16):

Just go to File->New Model, then Database -> Synchronize with any source. You have to be in model view to see this option in the Database menu.

Answer (score 6):

you can open "Model view"

[image]

and choose "Compare schemas" option

[image]

Comment: This menu option is not available until after generating an EER Diagram. Maybe explain how where Model View is?

Comment: Don't have to create an EER diagram. Just click New Model and then go to mentioned option.

Comment: You wont get this menu unless you follow these steps Just go to File->New Model>Databases>Compare...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps below:

1 - Menu **File** / **New Model**

[image]

2 - After opening the other screen, open the menu **Database** / **Compare Schemas**

[image]

3 - Select the option **Live Database Server** in both Source and Destination sections, then press on the **Next** button (My case I would compare 2 databases from cloud server)

[image]

4 - Select the stored connection for the **Source Database** (If the connection string is not created yet, you can create one), then press the **Next** button

[image]

5 - Select the stored connection for the **Target Database** (If the connection string is not created yet, then you can also create one), then press the **Next** button

[image]

6 - Click on the **Next** button

[image]

7 - Click on the schemas you want to compare in both sides: Source and Target, then press the **Next** button

[image]

8 - Wait until this step is complete and then press the **Next** button

[image]

9 - Finally check the results, you can copy and paste it outside for a better review

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a tool that can be used to compare two Databases. This Tool only works with MySQL. This tool generates SQL for Target Database to sync the database.
This is a web application tool built in CakePHP 2, you have to download code put into xammp->htdocs in case of windows, and make a virtual domain before using it. For more information goto below Link

https://github.com/hardeepvicky/MySql-Schema-Compare

Comment: Sir, I edit the answer as you commented. This is a free tool, just want to make an easy database syncing process.

Comment: Thanks. I think that looks like a better answer