# Ready to use php script to compare mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I just want to compare two mysql tables (with the same structure, actually these are two versions of the same table) visually to see the difference:

- see modified/added/removed records
- for modified records emphasize (e.g. by colour) which columns were modified.

Of course I can write it myself but why reinvent the wheel.

#### Is there any such ready-to-use PHP script available?

Solutions that don't need any framework are preferred.
Please don't post code, I can do it myself if necessary. I'm only asking about ready & tested tool.

Comment: why the downvote and close vote? I'm not asking about the best tool, I'm asking if it exists. because I haven't found one. This is allowed. Why be so hostile?

Comment: I got db-dumps (only structure) and pasted it in [diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) . It's not a ready php-script, but can help, if u just want to compare, and not to implement comparison logic into your project.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases). Might be something you need. Also here are something about unmatching rows http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx.

Comment: Andrius, the first link is great, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunatelly I haven't found the PHP tool there, only Windows/ASP :(

Comment: So that http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/ wasn't useful after all?

Comment: Seems that Toad runs under Windows, so that I would need to connect to the database from my desktop computer. This is complicated as the database server is behind firewall of the hosting provider. That's why I was looking for server-side PHP solution... I guess the PHP script could be quite simple - someone must have already written it...