# Is it possible to merge dumps from two MySQL servers?

Tags: merge, mysql

I have two mysql servers, both of which are masters. After some problems with their local network they lost connection with each other but continued working some time, without any synchronization. Both of them store some data from this period, and it would be bad to lose part of it.

Is it possible to merge dumps from these servers with any util?

Comment: So you had a master-master replication setup?

Comment: See the answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could find pt-table-sync helpful. But be sure to use it on backups of your data for safety and to reset the replication after using it as the changes you make will be replicated to the origin server if not.