# Comparing two tables for consistency (Mysql) with a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 databases, one for the operations and one for analytics.

The analytics database is not 1:1 the same as the operations database but still very similar.

Now I loaded archive files (csv) into the analytics database (it was empty before).

I have my old data in the analytics and my current data in the operations database.

I want to write a query to find out if some of the newly loaded records were already in the database.

Is there a way to check this out?

EDIT:

First of all I'm sorry. Made a mistake after looking at my database. I don't need to compare two different databases, while copying the operations database via phpmyadmin I forgot to load the current data into the analytics database. 
So I just need to compare 2 tables in one database, whether some of the old records were already in the database.

My first idea is/was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orderlinesold t1 
LEFT JOIN orderlines t2 on t1.orderid = t2.orderid;
```

but after running that query I get the hole rows as a result which is impossible --> wrong query.

How can I check up if some of the old data are still in the new one?

PS: Tables are in the comments as a link.

2. EDIT:

Ok I solved it. Was just a little comparing query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ordersold t1  
INNER JOIN orders t2 ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid 
LIMIT 100000000;
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orderlinesold t1 
LEFT JOIN orderlines t2 ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid 
WHERE t2.orderid IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 100000000;
```

Both discard the correct result.

Still thanks. This post can be closed.

Comment: Please provide the table formats for the two tables.  Better yet, provide SQL that gives an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Looks like this thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases?rq=1 . Otherwise you could write queries for each table to analyze that, maybe using an `IN` or `NOT IN` clause.

Comment: here my tables: http://imgur.com/XpgwI35

Answer (score 0):

there are tools to help you compare two databases but the basic technique that you can use, assuming you can rely on a primary key to identify missing records, is:

```
select    oo.id
from      operations.orders oo
left join analytics.orders ao 
on        oo.id = ao.id
where     ao.id is null
```

Comment: thanks, but i edited my thread, cause i dont need to compare 2 databased anymore, but 2 tables if there are same ids. would this query be correct? 
    SELECT * FROM orderlinesold t1 LEFT JOIN orderlines t2 on             t1.orderid = t2.orderid 
    where t2.orderid is not null limit 30000;

Comment: No, you have to look for IS NULL in the table with fewer records. Assuming orderlines has more records than orderlinesold, then it should be: SELECT * FROM orderlinesold t1 RIGHT JOIN orderlines t2 on t1.orderid = t2.orderid where t1.orderid is null limit 30000; Note that I changed also LEFT to RIGHT.