# What is best tool to compare two different Database ,the first database is Ms Sql and another is DB2

Tags: sql, db2, compare

I have two database , 
First Db is Microsoft SqlServer (version 2008 R2) and second database is DB2

i need a tool for comparing schema and tables in both ot them ? 
is every body have idea or solution ?

Comment: i search at google and found  a lot of tools which them designed for One type of DBMS

Comment: Consider asking at dba.stackechange.com

Comment: It does not meet criteria for this site. It is off topic, not a specific programming problem, and seeks opinion-based answers. See about [http://stackoverflow.com/about] above.  It would be better placed on the sister site for database administrators [http://dba.stackexchange.com]. The down vote was not meant personally, but it was my hope that it might help attract moderator attention, so that they would move it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/) can do that. I don't know if it's the best tool, as you didn't say how you'd define "best".

Comment: this is not free , please can you help me for download terial verision?

Comment: Seriously? It says **Available at no charge** in big bold black letters right at the top of that page.

Answer (score 3):

I Found DB SOLO 4.2. Software on site : 
http://www.dbsolo.com/help/compare.html

and i  checked it . 
thanks your time

Comment: at another post in stackoverflow by link saied other desctiption :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ***Toad*** or else you can also use ***SQL Developer***. Although ***SQL Developer*** would be a better option as you can view your MySQL database objects in it and once the DB2 Catalogs entry has been made, you can view the database objects of DB2 as well through the same tool.

Hope that helps.

Regards,
DB2 DBA