# Compare two different databases

Tags: database, compare

I have two databases, DB mysql & DB Access.
I want to compare two the same tables from this different databases about data and schema.
I need a tool for do it. Can you help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only for 2 tables with identical columns, the best way would be to extract the data into and ordered csv and use a diff tool to compare the files. If you want to compare many tables and the table structure you'll need to extract each in turn.

Answer (score 6):

With DataGrip, you can select 2 databases, right-click and select Compare.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it the best but [IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/) can do that if I'm report to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647566/what-is-best-tool-to-compare-two-different-database-the-first-database-is-ms-sq).

Answer (score 0):

You could use JetBrains IDE data grip and dump both files out and then compare using either excel or CLI