# MySQL Data Comparision from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Any method or tool ( opensource will be preferable ) to compare multiple table data in mysql. 
I check this link [Compare Mysql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases), but tools here are mostly based on windows platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://torasql.com which supports various Linux distributions, Mac OS X, MS Windows, and UNIX platforms.

Comment: it's not working on ubuntu 14.04. Require some libraries of older version with dependencies. Can you suggest me some alternative tools