# Python MySQL Comparing two tables

Tags: python, mysql

I want to learn how to compare two tables in order to find unmatched records.

I´m a total beginner to MySQL and therefore struggling currently in order to find out which query to use for comparing two tables.

Suppose, I have two tables that are identical in structure.

Table 1 (Old)

```
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "id" | "name" | "price" | "description" | "country" |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "1"  | "a"    | "2"     | "Lord "       | "US"      |
| "2"  | "b"    | "3"     | "Taker"       | "UK"      |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

Table 2 (New)

```
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "id" | "name" | "price" | "description" | "country" |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "1"  | "a"    | "5"     | "Lord"        | "DE"      |
| "2"  | "b"    | "6"     | "Taker"      | "JP"      |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

Table1 holds the outdated data and table2 the newest one.

I want to check if name, price, description fields from table 2 have any match to name, price, description fields in table 1. If not, it should update table 1 with data from table 2.

I checked out the folling site in order to find out to use which Mysql query:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx

But I cannot figure out how to write it down in Python.

I am new to using SQL statements in python and I have attempted it as,

```
 import sys, mysql.connector
 import mysql

 try:
     connection = mysql.connector.connect\
         (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd ="", db = "local")
 except:
     print("No connection")
     sys.exit(0)

 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT name, price, description FROM table2_new WHERE
```

I´m do not really have a clue how to continue. I searched for similar tasks but do not fully understand how to do it in Python.

Thats the desired output for table 1, the prices should be updated:

```
    +------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
    | "id" | "name" | "price" | "description" | "country" |
    +------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
    | "1"  | "a"    | "5"     | "Lord "       | "US"      |
    | "2"  | "b"    | "6"     | "Taker"       | "UK"      |
    +------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

Could you guys help me out? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are a beginner you have automated tasks that can compare and sync the data that are available in Workbench,SQLyog,Navicat,Toad. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases)

Comment: Please provide the expected output!! i.e. `table_1` after `update`

Comment: If it's not too late I would suggest to change your DB structure. Merge the two tables and add a column that indicates if the item is outdated or not.

Comment: You are trying to tackle several problems at once. Go one by one. I would start with learning to deal with databases directly, without python (e.g. Toad or Navicat). Next question, since you are a beginner, are you sure you want to have two tables with the same structure? That seems like it might be useful only in some very specific advanced situations. Next, python: I would suggest that you avoid learning the low-level DB API an try an ORM - sqlalchemy is great.

Comment: @Praveen: I provided the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, by which field(-s) your tables binds? Let's name it `bind_field`. If there are more than one field, then it will be `bind_field1`, `bind_field2` and other. Your query:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.bind_field = t2.bind_field [AND t1.bind_field1 = t2.bind_field2 ...]
SET t1.name = t2.name, t1.price = t2.price, t1.description = t2.description
```

The query updates fields `name`, `price`, `description` of `table1` with values from `table2` only for rows, which have same `bind_field` (-s, if there are more than one bind field).

`ON` statement allows you how your tables bind.
`SET` statement allows you to control updating values.

And it seems to me that you use text (`VARCHAR` or same) type field with id. If this is it, than your should change it to number-type field like `INTEGER`;

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Appreciated it. Stupid question: I have to write it like that in python, right? cursor.execute("UPDATE table1 t1") cursor.execute("INNER JOIN table2 t2")   Thanks for your feedback:)

Comment: no, that is one fully query: cursor.execute('update table1 t1 inner join table2 t2....')

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
update table_1 a
join table_2 b
on a.`name` = b.`name` and a.`description` = b.`description`
set a.`price` = b.`price`
```

Demo [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a70e9d/1)

This `query` will update `price` of `table_1` with `price` of `table_2`, if
`description` and `name` match. (beware of more than one match which wont give the result that you expect)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What do you exactly mean with "(beware of more than one match which wont give the result that you expect)" I dont get it fully

Answer (score 1):

your SQL Query will be something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.name = t2.name
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.name != t2.name
```

Then repeat for each field.