# Merge/Sync Two Joomla Databases - OSX

Tags: mysql, joomla, merge, synchronization, joomla2.5

I've got two Joomla 2.5.4 databases in .sql format. Both have been updated since they were initially cloned. One has some new modules, templates, etc. while the other mainly has content updates.

What are my options in getting these two .sql files merged into one while ensuring that when I upload the new db into production, given the assets make it there safely as well, the page will be updated without any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an automatically way to do your request. However, you can do this in some steps:

Step 1

Check the number of tables in both of your databases. Maybe new modules insert some new tables.

Step 2

Suppose one of databases as initial and other as secondary. If they have same database prefix, change the second one to something else and import it to the initial database. In this way you could test it easily just by renaming the prefixes and table names.

Step 3

Your contents are related to these tables:

```
categories
content
content_frontpage
content_rating
```

Take care "categories" table might be used by some extensions too, recheck it to ensure everything is OK.

Step 4

Your extension related tables are:

```
modules
modules_menu
extensions
template_styles
```

Step 5

There is one table that share with all contents and extension:

```
assets
```

Check and merge this table manually.

Also you can use compare tools to help you in this case:

[Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like template_styles was another one to consider. I'm a bit concerned about modules_menu as that one has some significant differences. I'm wondering if setting up modules/templates first would be best and then going through the content/menus and linking everything back up. Does modules_menu need to go with modules or are they independent?

Comment: It is optional item which add menu to modules. All modules with default configuration do not use this table unless you set it. More information about module rendering: https://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Joomla-Tips/how-joomla-handles-module-display.html

Comment: Got ya, that makes sense. Thank you for the additional info as well.

Comment: I ran a sync preview in Navicat between both of the db's and it logged over 800k+ differences. Is that common when both sites experience minor changes to module content or is it possible that these had never been the same db from the start?