# Can mysqldbcompare provide a sql patch?

Tags: diff, mysql, patch

What I want is a way to compare two versions of the same database and generate a sql file that updates DatabaseOld to DatabaseNew.  [Mysqldbcompare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.4/en/mysqldbcompare.html) sounds like it *might* do that, but it is not clear to me how.

Has anyone used mysqldbcompare for a usecase like this?

I have seen some attempts to diff dumps (eg [Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases#8718572)) and such, but I'm looking for something a little more robust and reliable than that.

Comment: you can use the percona tool pt-table-sync. That can synchrince  two table or Schema and that can find out what to do and only copy the missing row or delete or update the other

Comment: Interesting tool.  Am I right in thinking that it only operates on databases with an existing master-slave relationship?  That's not the case for me - I need to migrate data from a staging server to a production server.

Comment: no, you must not have a replication. this tool synced table / databases. the only thing ist that the strcture of the tables must be the same

Answer (score 0):

I see you never got a true answer so maybe this will help someone that is searching. `mysqldbcompare` will at least come close to what you are after. The issue I note so far is it will let you know tables are missing but not provide the `CREATE` statements. Another potential issue may be altering `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields. Here is the statement I am using to get just the schema differences (I don't care about data).

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=root:password@localhost test:prod --changes-for=server2 --difftype=sql --show-reverse --run-all-tests --skip-row-count --skip-data-check > C:\Temp\DBCompare.sql
```

This will provide output like this:

```
# WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases test and prod on server1
#
# Transformation for --changes-for=server2:
#

ALTER DATABASE prod CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

#
# Transformation for reverse changes (--changes-for=server1):
#
# ALTER DATABASE test CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
#


# WARNING: Objects in server1.test but not in server1.prod:
#    PROCEDURE: my_test_noout
#        TABLE: test
#    PROCEDURE: my_test
#        TABLE: customer2
#        TABLE: ordgdnames
#
#                                                   Defn    Row     Data   
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check  
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# TABLE     arahst                                  FAIL    SKIP    SKIP    
#
# Transformation for --changes-for=server2:
#

ALTER TABLE `prod`.`arahst` 
  ADD INDEX idx_arahst_CustId (CustId);

#
# Transformation for reverse changes (--changes-for=server1):
#
# ALTER TABLE `test`.`arahst` 
#   DROP INDEX idx_arahst_CustId;
#


# TABLE     aropen                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP    
# TABLE     brkitem                                 FAIL    SKIP    SKIP    
#
# Transformation for --changes-for=server2:
#

ALTER TABLE `prod`.`brkitem` 
  DROP INDEX ItemId, 
  DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_brkitem_ItemId (ItemId);

#
# Transformation for reverse changes (--changes-for=server1):
#
# ALTER TABLE `test`.`brkitem` 
#   DROP INDEX idx_brkitem_ItemId, 
#   ADD PRIMARY KEY(`ItemId`), 
#   ADD UNIQUE INDEX ItemId (ItemId);
#


# TABLE     category                                FAIL    SKIP    SKIP    
#
# Transformation for --changes-for=server2:
#

ALTER TABLE `prod`.`category` 
  DROP INDEX GrpId, 
  DROP INDEX CatId, 
  ADD INDEX idx_category_GrpId (GrpId), 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_category_CatId (CatId);

#
# Transformation for reverse changes (--changes-for=server1):
#
# ALTER TABLE `test`.`category` 
#   DROP INDEX idx_category_GrpId, 
#   DROP INDEX idx_category_CatId, 
#   ADD INDEX GrpId (GrpId), 
#   ADD INDEX CatId (CatId);
#


# TABLE     cusord                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP    
# TABLE     customer                                FAIL    SKIP    SKIP    
#
# Transformation for --changes-for=server2:
#

ALTER TABLE `prod`.`customer` 
  DROP INDEX ID, 
  DROP INDEX CustId, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY(`ID`), 
AUTO_INCREMENT=2200037;

#
# Transformation for reverse changes (--changes-for=server1):
#
# ALTER TABLE `test`.`customer` 
#   DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
#   ADD INDEX ID (ID), 
#   ADD UNIQUE INDEX CustId (CustId), 
# AUTO_INCREMENT=11048819;
#
```