# Compare two sql files

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, compare

I wold like to compare two databases (a backup from a few months ago and the fresh backup). What tools and ways are appropriate? I know how to use phpMyAdmin, how to export database but I wonder how to check differences between database currently working and backup. I only have an access to database using cpanel / phpmyadmin, no ssh.

I have tried so far to compare two sql files using git but they are too big to do it this way efficiently.

Comment: Are you wanting to compare the data in the databases, or the schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases?rq=1

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640420/compare-2-large-sql-files-and-find-differences-to-recover-data/78178843#78178843