# How to update Table columns without losing data

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have existing table that contains

**`id|name|age|gender|`**
and this one contains a data already which is

```
id|name     |age|gender|
------------------------
1 |mengaw   |18| Male  | and more.....
```

now i updated my database on localhost
becomes

**`id|name|age|gender|email|phone|country|city|`** the data of new table is updated.

so how can I update my table columns? instead of doing a insert code again?

Im using mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I think that you need a tool to compare schema and data between databases. Or perhaps the best it's to delete the first table and copy the table that you have on localhost.

Comment: @jarrlh phpmyadmin

Comment: @PHX255 but how about the data? because in localhost are outdated data's only the columns are updated

Comment: I that case use Quest Toad for Mysql. You can do a schema compare and sync the structure of both databases (source and destination).https://www.toadworld.com/p/downloads you have 30 days with Trial.

Comment: See this link ->https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86107/how-can-i-export-just-the-structure-of-a-mysql-database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases more tools for schema sync

Comment: ok guys i will check those links and update