# Is there a way to compare two create table queries and alter the existing table with adding new columns?

Tags: mysql

So in this case, I will get the whole database schema multiple times. But everytime the tables structure might be slightly different than the previous one. Since I already have data inside, is there a way to write a query to compare with the existing table and just adding new columns?

For example I already have this table in my database.

`` CREATE TABLE `Ages` (
  `AgeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgeName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgeAbbreviation` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YouthAge` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4; ``

And in the new schema that I get has the same table but with different columns.
`` CREATE TABLE `Ages` (
  `AgeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgeName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgeAbbreviation` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YouthAge` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AgeLimit` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4; ``

In this case the column `AgeLimit` will be add to the existing table.

Comment: You can of course always compare the queries by hand and write an `Alter table` query. You could also write some script retrieving the current table structure and parse the incoming structure and generate the `Alter table` query automatically. But I doubt you can do that with pure SQL. You'll need some external script in some other language doing the parsing and query construction

Comment: Checking if a certain column exists on either definition should be quite easy. It may be a bit more complicated, when columns also may change their definitions

Comment: That's why I am asking here. I know I can always compare by hand but there are hundreds of tables in the file I get which I have to convert them to string and try to grep the column name for each table to compare with those existing ones. Also, I feel really buggy by doing in this way!

Comment: As I said, I don't think it's possible with sql only (especially if you have the new Schema given as a textfile) but you may need to code this with whatever scripting language you are comfortable with (eg js, c#, python, ...) There is definitely no `create or alter table` command in MySQL

Comment: Yea I know, I write my whole backend in Node.js. I am just asking if there's a way in pure sql. I can just compare the queries I get with those existing columns. But it's just I feel like this is not a great way since I am taking the sql as string and try to grep the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by looking at the table definitions in the metadata tables (information_schema).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can always look into the existing schema using the `information_schema` database, which holds the metadata.
2. You can then import your new schema into a temporary database, creating all tables according to the new schema and then again look into the metadata.
3. You might be able to use *dynamic sql* inside a stored procedure to execute `alter table` statements created from that differences at runtime

But I think, this is a lot easier from the backend nodejs server, because you can easily do step 1 and 2 also from nodejs (it's in fact just querying a bunch of tables) and you have way more possibilities to calculate the differences, create and execute the appropriate queries.

*EDIT 1*

If you don't have the possiblility of creating a temporary database from the new schema, you will have to find some other way, to extract information from it. I suspect you have a sql-script with (among others) a bunch of `CREATE TABLE ...` statements, because that's typically what `mysqldump` creates. So you'll have to parse this script. Again, this seems to be way easier in javascript, if it even is possible in a MySQL stored procedure. If your schema is as well structured as your examples, it's actually just a few lines of code.

*EDIT 2*

And maybe you can event get some inspiration from here: [Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases?rq=1)  There are some tools mentioned which do a synchronization between databases.