# I want to check two tables if all their contents are similar

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to check two tables if all their contents are similar
and echo yes or no Similarity.
my PHP script is not work:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include($path."db.php");
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM thprtins";
$sqlt = "SELECT * 
        FROM thirdparty";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$resultt = $conn->query($sqlt);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = "" . $row["id"] . "";
        $expiry = "" . $row["expiry"] . "";
        $type = "" . $row["type"] . "";
        $financial = "" . $row["financial"] . "";
        $coid = "" . $row["coid"] . "";
        echo "$id.$expiry.$type.$financial.$coid<br>";
     }
}
if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) {
    while($rows = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $idd = "" . $rows["id"] . "";
        $expiryy = "" . $rows["expiry"] . "";
        $typee = "" . $rows["type"] . "";
        $financiall = "" . $rows["financial"] . "";
        $coidd = "" . $rows["coid"] . "";
        echo "$idd.$expiryy.$typee.$financiall.$coidd<br>";
    }
}
if ($result === $resultt) 
    echo "Two tables are similar"; 
else {
    echo "no Similarity ";
};
 ?>
```

I have a main table and a backup table and somewhere I just change the backup table. If the two tables are not equal, I want to do the equalization operation.

Although the content in the two tables rows is different, the output is:
Two tables are similar

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `if ($result === $resultt)` is unlikely to be what you want.  What makes these 2 tables equal?

Comment: I want is not a question. Please explain what answers you are looking for.

Comment: I have a main table and a backup table and somewhere I just change the backup table. If the two tables are not equal, I want to do the equalization operation.

Comment: What if you serialize the two databases and then check if they are the same?

Comment: @undry How does it work?

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I changed the backup table I want update the main table with the backup table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two MySQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat all columns of each row into one field using MySQL `CONCAT()` and then concat all rows into one row using `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`id`,',',`expiry`,',',`type`,',',`financial`,',',`coid`) SEPARATOR ',') AS `all_data` FROM thprtins";
$sqlt = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`id`,',',`expiry`,',',`type`,',',`financial`,',',`coid`) SEPARATOR ',') AS `all_data` FROM thirdparty";
$result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_assoc()['all_data'];
$resultt = $conn->query($sqlt)->fetch_assoc()['all_data'];
if ($result === $resultt) 
    echo "Two tables are similar"; 
else {
    echo "no Similarity ";
}
```