# OpenEdge database and Git

Tags: git, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

Is there an easier way to be able to use git with OpenEdge database changes than dumping the db dictionary file as text and version handle it?

Maybe like the Roundtable version handling system than can see changes in db (that cost way too much).

Comment: Most likely you are out of luck. We track DB-changes by storing incremental df-files in a directory. That directory could of course be tracked in git/another tool. Roundtable is a niche product and you won't find lots of third party tools that support Progress.

Comment: Also, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175451/how-do-you-version-your-database-schema

Comment: If you are making changes with SQL, you could version control your SQL statements and store the sha-1 in your database. When updating your database, git diff from HEAD to the version stored in your database can be extracted and applied to OE. Migration techniques such as the ones used by PHP/Ruby/Python ORMs could also be used with SQL and OE.

Answer (score 0):

In a word. "No". I've been using Progress since V3 and Roundtable since it was launched. I also do Roundtable consulting work. If you want an alternative then you need something that can talk to the Openedge database as a client process. AFAIK there is nothing out there in the market place.

Remember also that Roundtable does a lot more than "versioning" the database. It also manages all of the interdependencies between the code and provides a slew of tools including "where used", trigers compiles in programs on an as-needed basis and handles migrations between workspaces.

If you should find anything, let us know - I'll be right on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have been using Roundtable for "where used" listings, I find I still depend on Linux "frep" and Windows "SLS" for more rigorous "where used"; and, pipe the result to a text file that can be further modified.