# Build a simple Android 360 videos playback app with gyroscope

Tags: android, android-studio, playback, gyroscope, 360-virtual-reality

I'm trying for almost a week now to find a way to build an Android app that can simply play a 360 video and to be navigated using the gyroscope sensor, No luck till now.

I just need some help to find a way to build this app using Android Studio.

Also I tried "Panframe" and I couldn't really get something out of it. Don't know if it so hard or complicated or whatever.

Thanks for your help in advance guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a version control system for database structure changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308/is-there-a-version-control-system-for-database-structure-changes)

Comment: Sorry Maheshwar Ligade, It's not even related to the question ,, But thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has introduced this VR View. It might help.
Learn more-https://developers.google.com/cardboard/vrview

Comment: Oh that looks useful .. Will check it .. Thanks @Arnav M.

Comment: That documentation totally helped .. Thanks a lot Arnav for your quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[MD360Player4Android](https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android)**. This does what you want. It rotates the 360 video on Motion as well as touch basis.

[image: Image Demo]

Comment: Thanks Nadeem for you reply ,, It helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this sample](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started#game_features) game from google might be a good starting point [image]

[Here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/package-summary) is a api documentation for android if you need it.

Comment: Thanks Somesh for your reply ,, It's very useful info to build a cardboard based app