# Database Design Theory For Multiple Application Instances

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a SaaS project that will have each customer having an instance of the application (customer1.application.com, customer2.application.com, etc.) and ideally each customer would have their "own" space in the DB. The current plan is to create a DB for each customer and deploy an instance of the application into the web farm. The idea is that each customer could opt out of an upgrade to maintain the status quo (something one of our investors REALLY wanted, largely in part because he hates how Facebook keeps changing how it works.)

Last night I attempted to roll out, to my two test accounts, an update that altered the database. While the ensuing errors that were caused were my fault (forgetting a small but apparently very important change in the DDL) I'm starting to worry about my overall theory of operation because missing one ALTER COLUMN statement and a whole upgrade cycle could be blown to hell. So after that long build up here's my questions:

1) Is there a way to do a diff between two databases (the "test" production database and a actual production database) that will accurately record each change being made?

2) Is there another database (and/or application) design model I should be considering? I know if I take away supporting multiple versions of the application that I actually remove a lot of the long term support headaches.

Comment: You just need a better testing strategy.  You shouldn't be applying untested changes to a production DB.

Comment: I don't have a real production DB, I am currently working on my deployment method, and I've built two test customer accounts to test the upgrade process.

Comment: I'd like to point out that SQL Diff solutions DO NOT reliably cover the data changes that often take place during schema upgrades.  If you add a column, then normally you may populate it with some calculated data at the same time.  A SQL diff (while useful) is not safe to make large changes in a live database.

Comment: @Glen: According Code Complete, http://cc2e.com/, the best testers find at most 20% of the errors in any deployment.  So while adding tests improves quality, it's not a guarantee. You have to compare the benefits with the costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Food for thought:**

Code upgrades happen more frequently than DB Schema upgrades.  Make sure you have a **really good** SCM in place to handle the code upgrades.  We use `git` with great success.

Code is easy to manage, databases are not (in comparison).  The reason is that they are mutable, and change each moment.  Plus, they are really hard to roll back (possible, but time consuming, with downtime).  So we must arrive at a simple way to track schema updates (along with associated data changes), and be able to apply them in the future to other similar databases.

---

Each database schema version should be given a unique, sequential integer version number.  Start with 100 per say.

Each time you have to upgrade it, write an sql scripts like

- `100-101.sql`
- `101-102.sql`
- `102-103.sql`

It is the job of each script to perform the upgrade for that specific version.  It can be as simple as adding a table, or as complicated as re-arranging foreign keys.  But in any event, they will be **reliable** in what they are designed to do.

You can apply any given script many times during testing (on fresh data) to ensure it will work as expected.

---

So when you find yourself needing to upgrade a client from version 130 to 180, you can safely apply the sql scripts (IN ORDER), and you will arrive at the correct destination.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should never be changing DBs by hand. Do it by a script that does all DDL changes, etc...

   Ideally, there should be a generic DB release script that uses DDL version as configuration/input.

   (and DDL changes should be tagged with a specific tag in a versioning system)
2. You can go Microsoft route re: supporting multiple versions as a headache - simply designate all versions prior to X (say 2 versions back) as un-supported. That way, you can support last 2-3 versions but don't waste resources on anything more, while allowing per-client flexibility to a large extent.
3. You should carefully weigh pros/cons of having versioned app/DB system like you propose.

   List the the pros (such as placating an investor, positive experience for a client when version changes unexpectedly that you mentioned - **translated into marginal probability to retain/add new clients who require such feature**, plus an easy way to do BETA/UAT testing, **plus a failrly wasy way to roll back the schema changes gone awry** by loading client's data into DB schema from prior version).

   List the cons (cost of DB space, cost of your time to implement, cost of support)

Compare the two and decide which is better for your business.

Comment: The DDL is applied through a script... I just didn't include a column add to a table that one of the new tables referenced. Hence inquiring about a DDL diff tool.

Answer (score 2):

Redgate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index_v2.htm) does a good job of comparing and diffing two SQL Server databases (warning: commercial third-party product).  Also, I think there's free stuff out there that does much the same thing.

If you want to be able to leave some customers behind on older versions of your product, it might make more sense to maintain a one-database-per-customer model, with the scripts for building each version of the databases under source control.  This keeps your customers isolated from each other, and even allows you to switch database vendors (e.g. from SQL Server to Oracle) or versions (i.e. from SQL Server 2000 to Sql Server 2005) on some customers while keeping other customers on the older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Manual run scripts will not work. Nor diff tools, for the matter. Diff works for 2,4 maybe 10 databases. But does not scale, because what you need is *reliability* in presence of failures (offline databases, server restarting all that).

You deploy by scheduling upgrade scripts. For instance, see how MySpace does this for over 1000 databases: [MySpace Uses SQL Server Service Broker to Protect Integrity of 1 Petabyte of Data](http://rusanu.com/2009/07/26/myspace-uses-sql-server-service-broker-to-protect-integrity-of-1-petabyte-of-data/). the key take is that they use a guaranteed, reliable, delivery mechanism (SSB) to deploy schema maintenance scripts. You need an asynchronous, reliable, mechanism to run scripts because destination databases may be offline, running scheduled maintenance, unreacahbe etc, and a reliable delivery mechanism like Service Broker can handle all the retries and related issues (handling duplicates, acknowledgments etc). You can also look at [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) for an example of how to handle script execution via SSB.

As for the scripts themselves, I recommend you start looking at your database schema and configuration data as a versioned resource. I have addresses this problem already several times, eg. see [Do you put your database static data into source-control ? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525591/do-you-put-your-database-static-data-into-source-control-how/1618597#1618597)

**Update**

I guess I own some explanation why I consider diffing a wrong approach. Just to makes things clear, I'm talking about deployments of hundreds of servers and thousands of databases. The original post compares itself to facebook and I whish them to have the success to reach that size, but also the questions asks about *design principles*, so I say that discussing about cloud level scale is appropiate.

I see two problems with diff tools:

- Availability. All diff tools work by connecting to both the 'master' and the 'copy', so they can do their job only when both are online. This creates a hot spot, a single point of failure, the 'master' copy, whose availability becomes critical for deploying upgrades. High availability always comes at a cost. It also leaves the problem of 'copy' availability as a minor implementation details, the upgrade scheme must handle retries and time outs and disconnects from the client on its own (not a trivial problem by any means).
- Atomicity. The diff tools expect a stable schema of the 'master'. This in effect places a freeze on 'master' while an upgrade is taking place. While this can be controlled on a small scale, on large scales it becomes a problem as upgrading the master itself to v. N+1 becomes a race against all the thousands of databases, when some may be still upgrading from v. N-1.

Script based solutions that ship the upgrade script to the 'copy' solve both of these problems. Also diff tools like the VSDB .dbschema based [vsdbcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) are better than a 'live' diff tool since the 'master' dbschema file can be delivered to the 'copy' machine and turn the whole upgrade process into a local operation.

Overall I also belive that script based upgrade, using metadata versioning, is supperior to diff based upgrade, because of reasons of testing and source control I had already talked about in the link to Q1525591.

Comment: Remus - the first statement you made is **patently** false. We do this on 100s of databases daily (in addition to 100s of client file systems). The easiest trick to accomplish is to compare against a "gold copy".

Comment: And the 100s of databases and 100s of file systems are 100% online and available? That's an industry first...

Comment: Nobody is claiming 100% uptime, and SSB doesn't even make sense.  There is only one database server!

Answer (score 0):

> if I take away supporting multiple
>   versions of the application that I
>   actually remove a lot of the long term
>   support headaches

Any change, however small, has a chance of breaking something that is important for someone.

So if you have multiple customers, rolling out a fix for customer 1 will upset customer 2.  It doesn't even have to be a bugged release; it might just be a change in behaviour they disagree with.  For most customers, not controlling the release schedule is simply unacceptable.

So I'd advise you to keep a different codebase for every customer.  Roll out fixes only after agreement with a customer.

There is a number of customers where this approach breaks down (think Yahoo mail), but reading your question I think you're safely below that number.  And for a compare tool, I can't help but agree with the posts suggesting Redgate's SQL Compare.