# How can I do version control of Database Schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

Is there away (Cheap or FLOSS) to do version control of SQL Server 2008 DB schema?

Comment: I've added a link to a SO post which explains doing version control through svn... Check it out in my edited answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a nice article by Jeff Atwood on [database version control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html)

You can use [Team edition for database professionals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718807.aspx) for this purpose

Here is a [list of tools](http://secretgeek.net/dbcontrol.asp) that you can purchase which can be used too:

[Red Gate SQL Compare from $295.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)

[DB Ghost from $195](http://www.innovartis.co.uk/home.aspx)

SQL Change Manager $995 per instance.

[SQL Effects](http://www.sqleffects.com/) Clarity standard ed. from $139

[SQLSourceSafe](http://www.bestsofttool.com/SQLSourceSafe/SSS_Introduction.aspx) from $129.

sqlXpress Diff contact for price. :-(

[Embarcadero Change Manager](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/db-change-manager-xe) contact for price. :-(

[Apex SQL Diff from $399](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_edit.aspx)

SQL Source Control 2003 from $199

[SASSI v2.0 professional](http://www.sqlassi.net/Features.htm) from $180

Evorex Source # shareware or $299+ (conflicting reports!)

**Edit** Just found this post which explains version control through svn: [Versioning SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173/how-do-i-version-my-ms-sql-database-in-svn)

Comment: we tried that - like most MS products, I suppose it can work if your entire development system is set up "The Microsoft Way" - however, in practice we found it extremely limiting and pretty much useless.

Comment: Thats the reason i added a link to point out to a list of tools that can be used to attain the same.

Comment: Red Gate SQL Compare is a great product.

Comment: Liquibase https://www.liquibase.org/ might be worthwhile to mention, I've just played around a bit but so far I really like it + it's free

Answer (score 1):

Create a database project for the database, in Visual Studio.  Check that project into a library system, such as SVN or Team Foundation Server.

Comment: +1: Beat me to saying "commit DDL to version control (IE: CVS, SourceSafe, SVN, Git, etc)".

Comment: @OMG: Yes, except CSV and SourceSafe. Never use it in 2011

Comment: Can I do this with an existing DB?

Comment: I don't know if they've fixed it yet - but we had major problems using database projects - see this article regarding data loss on incremental updates. http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/20/How-to-make-incremental-DB-update-script-in-VS2008.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is no easy option in an enterprise environment.

The three methods below are the main choices (irrespective of tool set used).

> 1) Dump entire schema into a file and store file in repository

PROS: Easy

CONS: Big file - difficult to manually edit - hard to see what has changed since last version - can't deploy it so would need some mechanism to prepare a DIFF script between Dev and Test/Live systems

> 2) Dump every database object into a separate file, stored in repository.

PROS: Very easy to see what has changed. Can produce deployment scripts for most objects easily (although some things would still require DIFF script e.g. Column Definition changes)

CONS: Have to run scripts in a certain order - managing that process can be quite difficult.

> 3) Treat every change as a separate operation with it's own sequentially numbered SQL script.

PROS: Easy for devs to create scripts, same scripts can be run against each platform (in theory)

CONS: Nightmare to manage - ordering can become an issue, very difficult to see what has changed in a release, or when a given object changed.

Having run with all 3 options, I would say that 2 was lovely to work with, but took ages to set up in the first place - getting all the scripts executed in the correct order took ages - and it STILL required use of a Database diff tool to generate scripts for UAT/Live. So I would now recommend a mix between 1 & 2.