# SQL Server - Checkout system for database objects?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if anyone knows any 3rd party tools or existing functionality in SQL Server 2008 so that when someone is working on a table or procedure, it is locked out to that individual. I have searched the net extensively and can't seem to find anything relating to this. We are facing a problem where two people may be working on the same stored procedures and whoever executes last gets the code change! This kind of functionality would come in handy. I think that a lock or check in/check out system would be benefit a project, any ideas?

I am already hooked up to Redgate source control, which does not provide this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: Editing the code is one thing, actually deploying it is another. It sounds like your real problem here is your process: you have too many people able to make changes in production, and they do not coordinate their work. I would focus on improving your process first, and tools are rarely able to fix process issues by themselves.

Comment: @Pondlife The point of this question was to find out if there is a way to lock a procedure or table, I am aware there are too many fingers in the same pie.

Answer (score 0):

Try and have a look at this SO discussion: [How do I version my SQL Server database in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173/how-do-i-version-my-sql-server-database-in-svn)?

It might not lock things like you want, but it would help to ensure code is recoverable. You could also consider using [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as some kind of a checking mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, already hooked up to source control with Redgate but doesn't allow me to lock an object which is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_version.aspx

Alternatively, try this: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/entrypage/5-minutes?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=sqlsourcecontrol&gclid=CK_qsPC5prUCFe7MtAodzC8ACA

Comment: Already hooked up to Redgate source control and no locking abilities are available